# Funny Character on Swedish Site

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that I am working on and I have changed the database to UTF8 and I did the same in the php file but the funny character still exist, what am I missing? Please the image below for better understanding.

The site is php and add mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); after the connection but the issue remains the same

Thank you in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kG7l.png

Comment: Have you checked the data? Is that a proper collation you've used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this is caused by the font you are using missing a character for that language symbol.

I would check that the font supports Swedish or switch to one that specifically says it supports it to eliminate that as a possible cause.